# Rede Neural com entrada de um escalar (tempo) e 3 valores de saída que não treina corretamente

Tags: machine-learning, redes-neurais, keras

Olá! Estou construindo uma rede que deve mapear valores de tempo a um vetor contendo 3 valores de concentrações de reagentes, simulando uma reação química do tipo A->B->C. Os valores das concentrações foram obtidos com o solver odeint e resolvendo as equações numericamente, tendo assim um conjunto de dados para alimentar a rede.

Estou utilizando o Keras, com a seguinte rede:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu')) #input layer [t]

model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))

model.add(Dense(3, activation = 'relu')) #output layer [CA, CB, CC]

model.compile(loss = "mean_squared_error", optimizer = "Adam", metrics = ['mean_squared_error'])

return model
```

Ao fazer o treino da rede, obtenho a seguinte curva de aprendizado:
[image: Curva de aprendizado do modelo]

No entanto, quando vou testar a rede para os valores de t utilizados como input, utilizando o seguinte código:

```
for i in range(len(t)):
  C.append(model.predict([t[i]]))
C = np.array(C)

plt.plot(t,C[:,0]);
plt.legend(['A','B','C']);
```

Obtendo a seguinte curva:

[image: Perfil de concentração do modelo]

Enquanto o correto seria algo próximo de:

[image: Concentrações reais]

Gostaria de saber o que pode estar causando este problema, e como resolver. Obrigado!

Comment: Voce esta certo quanto ao uso da funcao ```mean_squared_error```? É um problema de  regressão ou classificação?

Comment: Quanto a isso estou sim, é um problema de regressão. Basicamente a minha rede deve se ajustar à um conjunto de 3 equações diferenciais que são gerados pelos balanços de massa de cada componente.

Comment: Sao poucas informação para compreender daqui, mas aparentemente, seu problema pode ser de classficação. Se voce espera que sua rede gere as saidas [CA, CB, CC], prevendo se uma reação é do tipo CA, CB ou CC, voce tem um problema de classificao, se for caso mude a função de ativação para ```categorical_crossentropy```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que você está modelando seu problema de maneira equivocada (me corrija se eu estiver enganado, eu apago a resposta se for o caso).

Apesar de você estar interessado nas concentrações A/B/C ao longo do tempo, não é o tempo que deveria ser sua variável de entrada. Sua variável de entrada deveria ser as concentrações dos três reagentes no tempo t<sub>n</sub> e sua saída as concentrações em t<sub>n+1</sub>.

Não estou familiarizado com seu problema, mas imagino que você tenha 3 equações de estado do tipo:

<sup>dA</sup>/<sub>dt</sub> = c<sub>1,1</sub> A + c<sub>1,2</sub> B + c<sub>1,3</sub>C
<sup>dB</sup>/<sub>dt</sub> = c<sub>2,1</sub> A + c<sub>2,2</sub> B + c<sub>2,3</sub>C
<sup>dC</sup>/<sub>dt</sub> = c<sub>3,1</sub> A + c<sub>3,2</sub> B + c<sub>3,3</sub>C

Discretizando o tempo, sua equação de atualização dos valores deve ser algo como:

A(t<sub>n+1</sub>) = A(t<sub>n</sub>) + dt <sup>dA</sup>/<sub>dt</sub>
B(t<sub>n+1</sub>) = B(t<sub>n</sub>) + dt <sup>dB</sup>/<sub>dt</sub>
C(t<sub>n+1</sub>) = C(t<sub>n</sub>) + dt <sup>dC</sup>/<sub>dt</sub>

Até onde conheço, é isso que os solvers de equações diferenciais fazem nos bastidores - traduzem o sistema em equações de estado e resolvem a equação passo a passo (potencialmente utilizando dt adaptativo).

Se essas suposições estiverem corretas (ou ao menos na direção correta), o que te recomendo é o seguinte:

- Crie um dataset em que os X são as concentrações em cada passo e os Y são as concentrações no passo seguinte
- Se seu dataset original não tiver o dt constante, adicione a variável dt aos seus inputs, para que seu modelo possa aprender a considerar a duração do passo no cálculo das concentrações seguintes
- Separe um percentual deste dataset para validação (eg últimos 10% do período que você tem disponível)
- Treine uma rede neural com 3 inputs (ou 4, se incluir o dt) e 3 outputs, usando MSE como loss function
- Experimente outras funções de ativação na camada de saída. Você está usando outputs que ficam restritos no intervalo [0,1], então talvez possa usar como ativação a função sigmoid ao invés de relu. Lembrar que relu preenche [0,∞[
- Na sua camada de entrada, não use 1 como número de unidades. Lembrar que o número de unidades dá a dimensão da saída daquela camada, não da entrada. Ou seja, o número de unidades não precisa corresponder à dimensionalidade do seu input. Pra informar pro keras qual a dimensão do seu input, use o argument *input_shape* na declaração da camada, conforme abaixo:

```
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[3]))
```

(Repare o input_shape=[3], referente ao uso de 3 variáveis como input da sua rede).

Avise se tiver funcionado!